# How to create a new user with sysadmin privilege in Azure SQL Server?

Tags: sql, azure

I need to create a new user with sysadmin privilege.

I went to the Azure portal > Query Editor. Then I run this commands.

Unfortunately I got this error:

[image]

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Query editor doesn't support connecting to the master database. In order to create new users, you have to use sql server management studio and connect to cloud sql server then create login.

[Azure sql documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJqkC.png)